# UnknownFormat in rails spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I'm fairly new to rails and I'm trying to return a javascript file from a controller action.  In TDD fashion I'm trying to write a failing test first and although I've fixed a bunch of reasons it's failed since starting, I'm now up against an error that I'm not sure how to fix.  If I run it in a browser, it works.  But running the spec I get an error "ActionController::UnknownFormat" pointing to the respond_to do |format| line.

Here's the controller action...

```
def job_board
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And my spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ApiController, :type => :controller do
  describe "when using an invalid url/api key" do
    it "should return error" do
      get :job_board
      expect(response).to have_http_status(400) #bad request
    end
  end
end
```

And finally my routes.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'api/job_board' => 'api#job_board', defaults: { format: 'js'}
end
```

Any idea why the spec is throwing this error?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using format.json?

Comment: What's odd is no matter what format I list (format.json, format.html, etc) it continues to error on the line above it - respond_to do |format|

Comment: Try removing ', defaults: { format: 'js' }' in your routes.rb file?

Comment: If I remove that then it also breaks in the browser with the same error message.

Comment: Got it figured out.  I had to change the get :job_board in the spec to get :job_board, format: :js

Comment: @geoffswartz, create an answer and mark it as correct, to prevent people from trying to answer, and also to make it clear for whoever comes looking for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out. I had to change the

```
get :job_board
```

in the spec to

```
get :job_board, format: :js
```